# Rewrite scr of all images

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, path

I change hosting and some of images are linked to old hosting account and have 403 status. How can I rewrtite all of their src in functions.php?
For example I have image with scr `https://dsweb.su/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Main_demo.png` and I want to change first part so path will be `https://artweb.su/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Main_demo.png`. All images that have this part `https://dsweb.su/` should be changed to have this part instead `https://artweb.su/`. I think I can do this with htaccess rewriting but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Do you have SSH access on the new server?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yeah

Comment: I assume the paths of the images are in the wordpress database?

Can't you just run a MYSQL query to update and replace?

Comment: @AndreaOlivato they are in DB but paths are wrong. I asume that I need to make a rewrite rule with htaccess but I'm don't know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to SSH, the easiest way is to use the official [WP CLI](https://wp-cli.org/)'s `search-replace` command. Installation instructions are at the previous link and are system-dependent, so I won't go into them here.

First, make sure that you have a database backup, and that you **know how to restore it**, just in case. (*I do this process several times a week but at the end of the day, it is your database and I'm just a random stranger on the internet.*)

Next, `cd` into your site's root and we'll be running the following command. The first parameter (after `search-replace`) is the original string and the second is the new string. Keep reading my notes below on that before making any changes. The third parameter, `--recurse-objects` (which actually appears to be the default now, but I still manually type it) handles serialized data which is very common in WordPress. The fourth parameter, `--all-tables`, tells the searcher to use every table in the database, even if it isn't registered with WordPress. It is pretty rare to **not** use this flag. The last parameter, `--dry-run`, means "don't actually do it, just test and tell me the results.

```
wp search-replace "https://dsweb.su" "https://artweb.su" --recurse-objects --all-tables --dry-run
```

Once that completes, take note of the last message which will be something like:

```
Success: 1,234 replacements to be made.
```

If it says `0 replacements`, the string we are searching for could not be found. You'll need to handle that or post something here.

If it says an actual number, you can re-run the command removing the `--dry-run` parameter, and you should be all set.

### A note on the first two parameters

The first two parameters are **NOT** URLs and they are **NOT** domains! I cannot stress this enough. They are just arbitrary strings that happen to look like URLs.

If your database also has your domain with a WWW in the front, such as `https://www.dsweb.su`, that will not be found. Similarly, if your database has URLs that are not secure, such as `http://dsweb.su`, those won't be found. Because of this, I recommend running the search and replace a couple of times.

```
# secure, no www
wp search-replace "https://dsweb.su" "https://artweb.su" --recurse-objects --all-tables --dry-run

# secure, www
wp search-replace "https://www.dsweb.su" "https://artweb.su" --recurse-objects --all-tables --dry-run

# not secure, no www
wp search-replace "http://dsweb.su" "https://artweb.su" --recurse-objects --all-tables --dry-run

# not secure, www
wp search-replace "http://www.dsweb.su" "https://artweb.su" --recurse-objects --all-tables --dry-run
```

For the replacement, always use the same string, we're only changing what is searched for. These examples all include the `--dry-run` parameter which I always recommend so that you know what it is about to do.

Your opinion of your site's domain isn't important, by the way. You'd be surprised what you can find in there. Somehow, some way, these extra versions get stuck in there.

There's two other potential cases that can crop up, but one is pretty rare but the other is not uncommon.

The rare one is a protocol-less URL `//example.com`, but that's easy to search for.

The not uncommon one is a regular domain, `example.com`. You can search for that, but remember that email addresses start with that as well, so you have to be very careful when doing that replacement, and I really don't recommend running it.

Comment: It says: 
Error: This does not seem to be a WordPress installation.
Pass --path=`path/to/wordpress` or run `wp core download`.

Comment: Did you `cd` into your WordPress install folder where your `wp-config.php` file lives?

Comment: I forgot but when I did it and paste first command - nothing happened. No messages just new blank field to type a command

Comment: Try adding `--debug` to the command to see if you can see any obvious errors

Comment: `Error: The site has encountered a critical error. Learn more about debugging in WordPress. A critical error has occurred on the site.`

Comment: Maybe it's better to rewrite with htaccess? But I just don't know how

Comment: I would turn on `WP_DEBUG` to see what the problem is

Comment: I turned it on in `wp-config.php`. I still got this error: `wp search-replace "https://dsweb.su" "https://artweb.su" --recurse-objects --all-tables --dry-run --debug`. What should I do?

Comment: I'd turn on full PHP error reporting and check your debug log, and also install the official advanced version of [Health Check](https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/) and see if that reports anything that might need to be done, like enabling PHP extensions or upgrading things. Beyond that, without an actual error message, there probably isn't anything else that I can help you with.